# Android - launch event on wifi detected or "location changed"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-wifi, android-gps

To my knowledge android (studio) currently only supports wifi detection and GPS detection with a timer that runs, for example, once a minute and checks the location and currently available wifi signals.

I was wondering of there are any more efficient methods to implement this as the app needs to run in the background, for example if I happened to get to a shopping mall and my phone detects/loses a familiar signal it, or when im 50m away from my home.

I'm still rather new to android development so there's much I dont know about it but attempting to search for this information mainly provides examples of detecting wifi state changes rather than detecting new wifi signals without connecting to them